# WARNING: nonstandard use of escape in a string literal

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgresql-8.4, postgresql-copy

I have installed source code of Postgres version 8.4.18, I am trying to create a table from .CSV file. [image: (picture)]

I have created a table successfully when, I am trying to copy the location with command COPY population from 'C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Data8277.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;  i get the following error.

[image: Picture2]

```
WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
LINE 1: COPY population from 'C:\Users\xyz\Desk...
                             ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
ERROR:  could not open file "C:UsersxyzDesktop-Data8277.csv" for reading: No such file or directory.
```

Unable to sort this problem out

Comment: Double the backslashes.

Comment: Or use dollar quoting: `select  $$'C:\Users\xyz\Desk..'$$; 'C:\Users\xyz\Desk..'` per [Lexical Structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/sql-syntax-lexical.html) *4.1.2.4. Dollar-Quoted String Constants*.

Comment: Yes the issue has been resolved, now m getting an error that  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "‘"
LINE 1: ...'C:\Users\Zadane\Downloads\Popdata.csv' DELIMITER ‘,’ CSV HE...
                                                             ^
And if I remove delimiter, I get error COPY population FROM 'C:\Users\Zadane\Downloads\Popdata.csv' CSV HEADER;
ERROR:  could not open file "C:\Users\Zadane\Downloads\Popdata.csv" for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: Try with forward slashes: `C:/Users/Zadane/Downloads/Popdata.csv`.

Answer (score 2):

Set the parameter [`standard_conforming_strings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) to `on`, so that backslash in string literals is treated as a normal character. I hope you aren't using an ancient version like that for anything but for preparing an upgrade.